# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'.(2339) Typescript Generics error

Tags: typescript

I have a function called `updateArrayOfObjects` which updates the object in the array. I am passing a generic type to this function like below:

```
interface OtherIncomeSource {
  id?: string;
  incomeDescription?: string;
  amount?: number;
}

const otherIncomes = [
          {
            id: "#6523-3244-3423-4343",
            incomeDescription: "Rent",
            amount: 100
          },
          {
            id: "#6523-3244-3423-4343",
            incomeDescription: "Commercial",
            amount: undefined
    }
]

const updateArrayOfObjects = <T>(arrayOfObjects: T[], newObject: T, deleteObject: boolean = false): T[] => {
    const newArrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.slice();

  let index = newArrayOfObjects.findIndex((obj: T) => obj.id === newObject.id)
  if(deleteObject) {
    newArrayOfObjects.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    if (index === -1) {
      newArrayOfObjects.push(newObject);
    } else {
      newArrayOfObjects[index] = newObject;
    }
  }

  return newArrayOfObjects
}

const newData = updateArrayOfObjects<OtherIncomeSource>(otherIncomes, {id: '1233', incomeDescription: 'agri', amount: 5000})
```

I am getting an error at the below mentioned line when accessing `id`saying "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'.(2339)":

```
let index = newArrayOfObjects.findIndex((obj: T) => obj.id === newObject.id)
```

Below is the typescript playground link for a complete environment of this issue and in here the error is highlighted in red: [Example in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=1#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-bd3E8rfeDppuvNTEsO6sTBgbOoAoXLt13GAlmsKjsjskAIQgt+-yBfddGuRmBwMHw63IVBoKAsQcb9fwkbgKToSYAHIugSeJoIpcA-02Spql2VBoIQAR+EQq4Oi4aI+h6cx4yAA)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to provide a constraint for your generic type as follows: `<T extends { id?: string }>`

Update the line `const updateArrayOfObjects = <T>(arrayOfObjects: T[], newObject: T, deleteObject: boolean = false): T[] => {`

to `const updateArrayOfObjects = <T extends { id?: string }>(arrayOfObjects: T[], newObject: T, deleteObject: boolean = false): T[] => {`

Comment: Thanks the error is gone. It made me realize that I did not write a truly generic function because I am using `id` within the function. Now that I am passing `id` as an argument to the function, getting "No index signature"  issue. Trying to make this function truly Generic.

Answer (score 1):

I had a more complex case where the above answer didn't work for me.

This is what worked for me:

```
type SimpleTableProps<T> = {
  data: Array<T & { id?: number }>;
  ...
};

const SimpleTable = <T,>(props: SimpleTableProps<T>): JSX.Element => {...}
```