# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component which is a table and it can take any kind of data.

The definition looks like this:

```
type SimpleTableProps<T> = {
  data: Array<T>;
  ...
};
```

```
const SimpleTable = <T,>(props: SimpleTableProps<T>): JSX.Element => {...}
```

When looping over the data to create the table rows, I need to use a unique key -- I can't use the index as the order of the rows can change.

I have this at the moment:

```
{data.map((el, index) => (
  <tr key={el.id || index}>
   ....
  </tr>
)}
```

The issue is that typescript complains that `id` does not exist on type `T`, which makes sense.

I applied the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437690/property-id-does-not-exist-on-type-t-2339-typescript-generics-error) but now I get other errors from the usage of the SimpleTable where an id is not needed (i.e. when the data passed does not contain an `id` key):

```
Type '{ whatever: string }' has no properties in common with type '{ id?: number | undefined; }'.
```

I tried things like using `in`, `Object.has...`, `el.hasOwn`, and things like this, without success:

```
key={Object.keys(el).includes('id') ? el.id : index}
```

Any idea how to make it work?

---

Edit: simple reproduction here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-error-uqwmju

Comment: @RyanWilson it's a type indeed, I corrected it, thanks

Comment: The error is due to `T` in this case being a generalized type parameter which does not have an property id.

Comment: @Palladium02 indeed, any idea what's the way to make it work here?

Comment: "now I get other errors"  which ones?  Can you make the code a [mre] that shows what you're talking about?  I should be able to paste the code into a standalone IDE and demonstrate your issues for myself.  You might be able to constrain `T` like `<T extends {id?: string}>(props: ...` but I can't be sure without more info

Comment: @jcalz I updated my post with an example of the other error I get. Basically, when passing data that does not contain `{ id: number }`, it throws this `Type '{ whatever: string }' has no properties in common with type '{ id?: number | undefined; }'.
 `

Comment: Can you make the code a [mre] that shows what you're talking about? I should be able to paste the code into a standalone IDE and demonstrate your issues for myself.

Comment: @jcalz here is a simple reproduction https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-error-uqwmju

Comment: If you have extra fields, you need to tell TypeScript that it's fine to have extra fields

Comment: So you can fix that like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM43zN).  But the [mre] should be in plain text in the question.  Presumably you could just take the code from [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w6PgGm) of your example and put it directly in the question as plain text to go with your question.  I'd be happy to [edit] the question  myself, if you would prefer.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your help, but I'd rather not use `any` in the type definition. I actually made it work like this `data: Array<T & { id?: number }>;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it

```
type SimpleTableProps<T> = {
  data: Array<T & { id?: number }>;
  ...
};

const SimpleTable = <T,>(props: SimpleTableProps<T>): JSX.Element => {...}
```