# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User' ts(2339) when using generic method from an abstract class

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, objection.js

[TypeScript playground here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDkQBMAuOQmKZAcwG5yBfc80SWONgA2mQoQLEoASSSNMSXIgC2YIcCXAU4oiQpUEdBk1YceVbBFlMArthjQAFJSo16jZkhYAaZwEoyzlQwABYIhAB0BnAAvDQcVNzcvODQ8JgARu448MKi4gCCmUzZALIQ1MBCADwAKgB8AVQZWXZwSphgAGJQEEoAIgBCtXUOSuWV9IUtMGUV1fW%209DXxcM3Fre1gNRCDww7UvZjIS4twU%20sz4-N1HEl8qYIiYhJofcAwR0Kzlc6gqEjUApFKClK5VHRQOrkChmOAAegAVHAAAo9MBoGAIYDiBFw5wGAD8bmMnlMVE23V6uwhIzGc3oELeHwQXyupwhjRcFiscGskhicCQwAA7i9pFZ5LgnC4XHTKpFqKtxO5WD4Zb4yS4oO9rFAkLz%20aIxSskuSOttqZIRgd2scxezJEzPt8hJzzJZGHAeqLYkLRYz3s6rg4NYEvRBhQqBTajkgFWx4XC4CEwsngt7xPI4GgelA4AAiVEQdGwACecAA5AYK3ADtjBRB4KAwvBLMnS%20jKxCK%20Fk4QHAAmADMQ4AnL582HtTBdfrvSaeJwgA)

Let us define an interface:

```ts
export interface User {
  id: string;
}
export class UserInstance implements User {
  id: string;


  constructor(
    id: string,
  ) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Then, suppose we have an abstract class:

```ts
import { Model } from "objection";

export abstract class AbstractModel<T> extends Model {
  abstract mapFromDB<T>(model: AbstractModel<T>): T;
  abstract mapToDB<T>(domain: T): AbstractModel<T>;
}
```

and a concrete implementation of that class:

```ts
export class UserDetailModel
  extends AbstractModel<User>
{


  /* Properties */
  id?: string;

  mapFromDB<User>(model: UserDetailModel): User {
    const user = new UserInstance(
      model.id as string,
    );

    return user as User;
  }

  mapToDB<User>(domain: User): UserDetailModel {
    const row = new UserDetailModel();
    row.id = domain.id; // this throws an error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'. ts(2339)"
    return row;
  }

}
```

I do not understand that error. The interface `User` does have a property id. So why does it throw this error?

Is it because I am using generics in the wrong way? What I want to achieve in the end, is simply a conversion from my domain to my model, ready to be inserted in the DB (it is a model in the "Objection js" sense). Of course, the AbstractModel exists for all domain entity T.

I notice that the following works fine, so it really must be my use of generics that is wrong, but I do not get why:

```ts
  test(domain: User): UserDetailModel {
    const row = new UserDetailModel();
    row.id = domain.id; // no error 
    return row;
  }
```

It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437690/property-id-does-not-exist-on-type-t-2339-typescript-generics-error) but I do not really understand the reason.

Comment: Is this error happening at runtime or is it being reported by the compiler?

Comment: It is reported by the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have name confusion. Firstly this declaration

```
mapFromDB<User>(model: UserDetailModel): User
```

means that you have generic method with type parameter named `User`. It is not your `interface User`. So it has no property named `id`.

In order to fix it. You have to fix `AbstractModel` declaration first. In your declaration you haven't use class type parameter `T`. Instead you make both class methods - generic with their own type parameter `T`. You need to change `AbstractModel` like this:

```
export abstract class AbstractModel<T> extends Model {
  abstract mapFromDB(model: AbstractModel<T>): T; 
  abstract mapToDB(domain: T): AbstractModel<T>;
}
```

Next you should get rid of `User` type parameter

```
export class UserDetailModel
  extends AbstractModel<User>
{

  /* Properties */
  id?: string;

  mapFromDB(model: UserDetailModel): User { // removed <User>
    const user = new UserInstance(
      model.id as string;
    );

    return user as User;
  }

  mapToDB(domain: User): UserDetailModel { // removed <User>
    const row = new UserDetailModel();
    row.id = domain.id;
    return row;
  }

}
```

now it will work as expected without exception

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I correctly understand your answer, the problem was that I was using generic methods within a generic class, while these methods do not need to be generic and instead are usual methods that rely on the type parameter T of the generic class. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely correct!